# Laravel 5.2 PHP array to Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, laravel-5

Sorry for the beginner question.

I'm trying to use PHP array to Javascript variable.

But I got below console error:
[image]

This is my PHP,

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\test;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use DB;

class PricePinpointController extends Controller
{
  function index(Request $request){

    $test = DB::connection('test')->table('aaa')->where('seq', '111')->select('longitude', 'latitude')->get();

    $position = array($test[0]->longitude, $test[0]->latitude);

    return view('index', ['center' => json_encode($position)]);
  }
}

?>
```

And This is my index.blade.php,

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log({{$center}});
});
</script>
```

Could you help point out where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `{{ }}` the data/text echo'd is escaped.

> By default, Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through PHP's `htmlentities` function to prevent XSS attacks.

You just need to change these brackets to `{!! !!}` to avoid escaping the information:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log({!! $center !!});
});
</script>
```

You can read more about this in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#displaying-data).

Comment: Thank you very much! successed!!